# How to close ffplay when video is over?

Tags: ffmpeg

To get the duration time with ffprobe.

```
ffprobe test.mp3 2>&1 | awk -F'[ ,]' '/Duration/{print $4}'
00:03:51.05
```

To set duration time with -t argument.

```
ffplay  -t '231'  test.mp3
```

The ffplay command can't stop when test.mp3 is over.
How to close ffplay when video is over?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `-autoexit` i.e.

```
ffplay -autoexit -t '231'  test.mp3
```

Comment: Thankfully ffplay is smart enough to figure out when the audio is over so no need for the ffprobe the OP was using, but I find it surprising that exiting when finished playing isn't the default behaviors, especially when using `-showmode 0`.  What is the reason for this?